# what do the millisecond values in sys.dm_exec_query_stats mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sys.dm-sql

I've been trying to measure the execution time of some queries executed from an application. I've been trying to use sys.dm_exec_query_stats.last_elapsed_time 
but I'm confused about the values that it is returning. When I execute the query

```
SELECT TOP 1 qs.plan_handle, qs.last_execution_time, qs.last_elapsed_time, qs.min_elapsed_time FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs ORDER BY qs.last_execution_time DESC
```

from the ssms, it clearly executes and returns the results just as soon as the display can refresh, clearly much faster than one second. However, the values being returned for last_elapsed_time are consistently around 1700-1800 milliseconds.

What am I missing?

Here is the [msdn info page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) on sys.dm_exec_query_stats. I'm using sql server 2012.

Comment: What field is returning 1700?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear. "last_elapsed_time" is the field that I am most interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not millisecond values, but MICROsecond values, as is stated clearly on the msdn info page for the table.